# How can I solve this differential equation with fourier series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

[image: Formal solution for a partial diff eq]

Find a formal solution $u(x; y)$ by
using Fourier series.

(Hint: In two dimensions the basis functions have one
of the forms $\sin(ax) \sin(by)$, $\sin(ax) \cos(by)$ and $\cos(ax) \cos(by)$, with
appropriate values for $a$ and $b$).

I am not able to use this and get the solution: Can someone please help.

Comment: The hint is telling you that inner product of your basis functions are zero when take $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}fg \ dy \ dx$ and $f\neq g$.

Answer (score 0):

try the solution of the form $u = \sin mx \sin ny $. putting $u$ in the equation gives $Lu = u -3u_{xx} - u_{yy} = (1 + 3m^2 + n^2)u$  so that 
$$L^{-1}\left( \sin mx \sin ny \right) = \dfrac{1}{1 + 3m^2 + n^2} \sin mx \sin ny$$

for your problem you need to compute $$L^{-1}\left(\sin 2x \sin 3y - \sin 5x \sin y \right).$$